# SELECT from declared variable

Tags: sql

How can I select value from declared variable?

```
DECLARE 
val INTEGER;
BEGIN
select idTab1 into val from Tab1 where numTab1 = 0;
SELECT val; -- this value I want to select
END;
```

Comment: `select val from dual` ?

Comment: This looks like PL/SQL. Are you using Oracle? If yes, what exactly do you mean with "this value I want to select"? An anonymous PL/SQL cannot "return" a value.

Comment: thx, and what is dual?

Comment: `dual` is a special Oracle table which contains a single row and a single column; it acts as a hack to allow you to perform select statements without a real table (e.g. in MSSQL you can just do `select @val`; in Oracle you'd have to do `select val from dual`)

Comment: `dual` is the greatest hack in software history..

Comment: So what DBMS are you using? Oracle? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

You have done almost to right.

Please try with this

```
DECLARE @val Integer
SELECT @val = idTab1 from Tab1 where numTab1 = 0;
SELECT @val
```